# What is the probability of this subset containing both 'a' and 'b'?

Tags: probability

If $S =$ $\{$ $a,b,c,d,e,f$ $\}$ and $A$ is a subset of $S$ randomly chosen, then what is the probability that $A$ contains both $a$ and $b$ ?

I know that number of subsets of $S$ is $2^6$. Now, I also know that all the subsets that contain $a$ and $b$ are - $\{$ $a,b$ $\}$, $\{$ $a,b,c $ $\}$, $\{$ $a,b,c,d $ $\}$, $\{$ $a,b,c,d,e $ $\}$, $\{$ $a,b,c,d,e,f$ $\}$.

Hence, $P($ $A$ contains both $a$ and $b$ $) =$ $\frac{5}{64}$.

But that is not the right answer.....could someone please point out what is it that I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: $\{ a,b,f\}$ is another. There are more... (you can "add" any subset of $\{c,d,e,f\}$).

Comment: When you listed the subsets containing a and b, you only listed a few.  What about {a,b,d}, for example?

Comment: Hint:  try the same question on a smaller set.  e.g.  "What is the probability that a randomly chosen subset of {a,b,c} contains both a and b?"  If that's too easy, try {a,b,c,d}.  For small sets, you can always just enumerate the cases explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

The subsets of $S$ that contain $a,b$ can all be written as $\{a,b\}\cup T$ where $T\subseteq\{c,d,e,f\}$. How many sets $T$ are there?

Comment: $2^4 = 16$!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Where is a b and d for example ,you are missing some combinations , other then that there isn't to much to it just find all the possibilities

Comment: could you tell me how to figure out all the possible combinations without missing any one ?